# Estimation of line length using Skeleton

Tags: java, image-processing, imagej

I'm using ImageJ and Skeleton to estimate line length and density, but the problem is that I have an agglomerate of lines that I need that to be considered as different lines, before I can use the Skeleton plug in.

Has anyone have any idea of how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hye you may use the plugin strahler that gives you the number of branch between two junction by branch order. Perhaps you could try after to measure them
[enter link description here](http://fiji.sc/Strahler_Analysis)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new to writing scripts for ImageJ but I've found some of the plugins very helpful. The problem is extracting the skeleton length for individual objects, (I'm still learning how to do that). If your using Fiji.

Plugins -> Skeleton -> Analyze Skeleton